# xml file back up?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a asp.net application which reads and updates and xml file in my file system.I do have the options edit and save.As of now it serves my purpose but what if the user edits the values and saves but for some reason he wants to restore the old values to the xml file.I want to

1. have an option called reset which will get the old values of the xml file incase the user wants to get back to the default values.How do i create a back up to the original file and how do i call that xml file ???  Can any one suggest whether i am in right path or not?

I am using Linq-to xml here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a copy of the original XML file. Call it xml_file.bk and when the user clicks "reset" delete the current XML file and make a copy of XML_File.bk to the real name with the `.xml` extension.

You can use `File.Move(sourcefile, destinationFile)` to make a copy of the original.

[File.Move documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

Comment: I don't have access to the folder to keep a back up? can i create a back up on the fly?

Comment: Sure, you can. When you read it initially, just save it with a different name.

Comment: Will try that way and get back to you .Thank you.